# Any LaTeX video tutorial recommendations for Mac users?

Tags: learning, tutorials

I dive into LaTex world for a time, although I try my best to read *More Math Into LaTeX* come along with TeXShop, there are still lots of gaps uncovered.

I did search them on [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com) and I find nothing, so, any LaTeX video tutorial recommendations for Mac Users?

Comment: Why would such a recommendation have to be specific to Mac users? TBH, I'm not sure video is the best medium for learning LaTeX (or any programming language, for that matter)... Have you considered a [book](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)?

Comment: @Jubobs Does TexShop work on PC, too? Mac compatible resources is also OK. And for me, the best way to learn programming language is watching video tutorials. I am now watching lynda.com for learning HTML & CSS, I find those videos very useful.

Comment: TeXShop Mac specific but LaTeX is not. Unless the question is specifically about the front-end, it is largely irrelevant what platform you are on. (Exception: installing new packages etc. works differently for MiKTeX on Windows and MacTeX installs some aliases not created by TeX Live on GNU/Linux. But for coding documents, none of that makes any difference.)

Comment: To my knowledge, no such serious, good-quality videos exist. Since the domain is about typesetting, you *will* find a *ton* of very good written tutorials.

Comment: Most people writing guides, _etc._ very deliberately _avoid_ platform specific stuff! Other than a little bit of set up, things are the same on Windows/Mac/Linux if you use a cross-platform editor. For example, UK-TUG have standardised on TeXworks because it makes our life easier!

Comment: @SeanAllred *A a ton of very good written tutorials*, and that would be?

Comment: `texdoc lshort`, `texdoc texbytopic`, … these and many more are available via `texdoc`, which is just sitting on your machine.  See this [web mirror](http://www.texdoc.net/#id0) for more info, but note that documentation is actually the majority size-wise of your distribution.

Comment: Note that I'm very close to actually starting to record my own webseries on  LaTeX. I've been slowly accumulating material since this question was asked and have finally found the time (i.e. the job that gives me the time) to start producing :-) Once it's 'complete', I will link it here as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Summarising comments]

While you may find some resources recorded on a Mac, the vast majority of material will not make specific reference to any one platform. Most people writing guides, *etc.* very deliberately avoid most platform specific stuff. With the exception of actually installation TeX system, the same on Windows/Mac/Linux/... If you use a cross-platform editor (of which there are many: see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)).

Videos are useful for some aspects of learning LaTeX, but as it's a programming-like approach more 'traditional' resources such as books or written online guides are often more useful: see [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner) for some examples.